# jquery function inside html() action

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value

In jQuery how to make for looping function inside `html()` action

```
file = var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

$(".selector").html(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
       return "<li>"+file[i]+"</li>";
    }
});
```

these line of code return the only first string in file

```
<li>Saab</li>
```

but im looking for

```
<li>Saab</li>
<li>Volvo</li>
<li>BMW</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you were returning from the function itself from the first iteration of for loop, so it will only shows first one. So you can do something simple with help of **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**. There is no need for the loop and callback in your code.

```js
var file = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
$(".selector").html("<li>" + file.join('</li><li>') + "</li>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selector"></ul>
```

Or you can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var file = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
$(".selector").html(file.map(function(v) {
  return $('<li/>', {
    text: v
  })
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selector"></ul>
```

Comment: seem so easy :) but im confuse how it is

Comment: @mon-sun : read doc ,https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 mistakes in your code

**1st** is define array in wrong way

```
file = var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];  //wrong 

var file =  ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; // correct way
var cars =  ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; // correct way
```

**2nd** is wrong place of return statement inside the loop

Why is your code not working ?  because of  `return "<li>"+file[i]+"</li>";`
`return` stops execution and exits the function. `return` always exits its function immediately, with no further execution if it's inside a loop.

try this

```js
  var file =  ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    
    $(".selector").html(function(){
        var str =''
        for(i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
          str += "<li>"+file[i]+"</li>";
        }
     
        return str
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selector"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to define your vars this way: `var file = cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];` and you can use `Array.map()` method.

```js
var file = cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

$(".selector").html(function(){
  return file.map(function(el){ return "<li>"+el+"</li>"; });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selector"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

do you need to use .html?

Because looking at your situation, I would prefer using .each(). It should look something like this.

```
var file = ["a","b","c"];

$.each(file, function(index, value) {
    //create element using value;
    //append element to wherever you think is necessary
})
```

Comment: you have any idea why he use .html() ?

Comment: nope. I have never used .html(). The only thing I saw him trying to do is getting that output from the array :-?. So I recommend using .each since it's faster :-?